# Advice on generic try catch

Tags: c#, exception, generics

This is not so much of a problem but more feedback and thoughts. I have been considering an implementation for methods that have been tested thoroughly through our internal teams. I would like to write a generic exception catch method and reporting service.

I relize this is not as easy as a "try-catch" block, but allows for a uniform method for catching exceptions. Ideally I would like to execute a method, provide a failure callback and log all the parameters from the calling method.

Generic Try-Execute.

```
public class ExceptionHelper
{
     public static T TryExecute<T, TArgs>(Func<TArgs, T> Method, Func<TArgs, T> FailureCallBack, TArgs Args)
     {
            try
            {
                return Method(Args);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
                string method = "Unknown Method";
                if (stackTrace != null && stackTrace.FrameCount > 0)
                {
                    var methodInfo = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod();
                    if (methodInfo != null)
                        method = string.Join(".", methodInfo.ReflectedType.Namespace, methodInfo.ReflectedType.Name, methodInfo.Name);
                }
                List<string> aStr = new List<string>();
                foreach (var prop in typeof(TArgs).GetProperties().Where(x => x.CanRead && x.CanWrite))
                {
                    object propVal = null;
                    try
                    {
                        propVal = prop.GetValue(Args, null);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        propVal = string.Empty;
                    }
                    aStr.Add(string.Format("{0}:{1}", prop.Name, propVal.ToString()));
                }
                string failureString = string.Format("The method '{0}' failed. {1}", method, string.Join(", ", aStr));
                //TODO: Log To Internal error system
                try
                {
                    return FailureCallBack(Args);
                }
                catch
                {
                    return default(T);
                }
            }
      }
}
```

What I know as draw backs.

- Performance Loss using reflection
- MethodBase (methodInfo) may not be available through optimization
- The try-catch around the error handler. Basically I could use the TryExecute wrapper for the try-catch around the error call back however that could result in a stack overflow situation.

Here would be a sample implementation

```
var model = new { ModelA = "A", ModelB = "B" };
return ExceptionHelper.TryExecute((Model) =>
{
     throw new Exception("Testing exception handler");
},
(Model) =>
{
    return false;
}, 
model);
```

Thoughts and comments appreciated.

Comment: Exception handling shouldn't be used as a programming tool for logging errors. Exceptions should be only for exceptional purposes. The general rule is "If you just catch `Exception` then you are doing something wrong."

Comment: have you heard of the [codereview.se] site?

Comment: @codesparkle no, but I have now. Thank you. For future code reviews I will post there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's a *lot* of code to put in a `catch`, including *two more* `try`/`catch` blocks.  Seems like a bit of overkill if you ask me, with a good amount of risk that a further exception can obscure the actual exception and that the error information would be lost.

Also, why `return default(T)`?  Returning defaults or nulls as indications of a problem is usually pretty sloppy.  If nothing else, it requires the same conditional to be wrapped around every call to the method to check for the return and respond to... some error that has gone somewhere else now.

Honestly, that usage example looks pretty messy, too.  It looks like you'll end up obscuring the actual business logic with the error-trapping code.  The entire codebase will look like a series of error traps, with actual business logic hidden somewhere in the entanglement of it.  This takes valuable focus off of the actual intent of the application and puts something of background infrastructure importance (logging) at the forefront.

Simplify.

If an exception occurs within a method, you generally have two sensible options:

1. Catch (*and* meaningfully *handle*) the exception within the method.
2. Let the exception bubble up the stack to be caught elsewhere.

There's absolutely *nothing* wrong with an exception escaping the scope of the method in which it occurs.  Indeed, exceptions are designed to do exactly that, carrying with them useful stack information about what happened and where.  (And, if you add meaningful runtime context to the exception, it can also carry information about *why*.)

In fact, the compiler even subtly hints at this.  Take these two methods for example:

```
public int Sum(int first, int second)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
}

public int Product(int first, int second)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

One of these methods will compile, one of them will not.  The compiler error will state that not all code paths return a value on the former method.  But why not the latter?  Because throwing an exception is a perfectly acceptable exit strategy for a method.  It's how the method gives up on what it's doing (the *one* thing it should be trying to do and *nothing* more) and let's the calling code deal with the problem.

The code should read in a way that clearly expresses the business concept being modeled.  Error handling is an important infrastructure concept, but it's just that... infrastructure.  The code should practically *scream* the business concept being modeled, clearly and succinctly.  Infrastructure concerns shouldn't get in the way of that.

Comment: +1. Worth adding, not only are exceptions meant to escape methods, but when possible put the bit that might throw first. You want them to escape, and you want them to escape **fast**.

Comment: @JonHanna: Indeed.  The same is true for the scope of any given operation from the method scale to the application/domain scale.  Don't let a failure allow a unit of work to persist an unknown state.  Exceptions are _vastly_ preferable to side-effects.

Answer (score 6):

This is very rarely going to be useful.

It covers only cases where:

1. The method has a well-defined means of obtaining an appropriate return value in the face of failure.
2. You'd actually care to log that it happened.

Now, 2 is very common with exceptions of all sorts, but not where 1 is true too.

1 of course is rare, since in most cases if you could produce a reasonable return value for given parameters by means X you wouldn't be trying means Y first.

It also has a default behaviour of returning `default(T)` - so null or all zeros - if the fallback doesn't work.

This only works where your case 1 above has "something that just returns null as a result because we don't really care very much what this thing does", or where the called method never returns null, in which case you then test for null, which means that your real error-handling code happens there.

In all, what you've got here is a way in which exceptions that would be trappable by real code have to be caught for by testing (and sometimes testing + guesswork) instead, and those that would bring down a program in a clear place with nice debugging information will instead put it into a state where you don't know what's going on anywhere, but at least of the few dozen bugs that got logged before something managed to bring it down fully, one of the is probably the actual problem

When you've a catch on some exception for a particular reason, by all means log the exception. Note that this is not so much to help find bugs (if that exception being raised there is a bug, you shouldn't be catching it there), but to cancel out the fact that having a catch there could hide bugs - i.e. to cancel out the very effect you are deliberately encouraging by putting catches all over the place. (E.g. you expect a regularly hit webservice to fail to connect on occasion, and you can go on for some hours with cached data - so you catch the failure and go on from cache - here you log because if there was a bug meaning you were never trying to hit the webservice correctly, you've just hidden it).

It's also reasonable to have some non-interactive (service or server) app log all exceptions that reach the top of the stack, because there's nobody there to note the exception.

But exceptions are not the enemy, they're the messenger. Don't shoot the messenger.

Comment: I wish I could give another +1 if only for that last line.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and I understand what you are saying (and what others have said).. Basically, although this is a final catch solution it is not a pratical implementation or even a solution to manage exceptions or potential exceptions. This is exactly the feedback I was looking for. Cheers.

Comment: The closest thing I would have to something like your catch block, is something in main (for an desktop app) or global.asax (for a web app) than does that sort of logging (I'd just grab the stacktrace from the exception though, much simpler) before showing a "sorry, I messed up" message. Anywhere else it's shooting the messenger.